# Detect adb connection from the phone side

Tags: adb, usb-debugging

I want to know if the phone is currently connected to a host that can run adb commands from within the phone, no matter if it's using an app, a shell command constantly running, or any other method that doesn't require the host or an external server.

From the host, I can just run `adb devices`. Ideally, I would like to have something equivalent inside the phone, say `adbdaemon host-info` that let's my phone know that there is an existing adb connection with a computer.

Comment: Host side (`adb`) initiates the connection, phone side (`adbd`) responds to the received commands. You are looking for the inverse. `adbd` doesn't keep track of the connection, the host side does. Neither `adbd` provides a method to query current connection status. All that you can know is that phone is connected to a PC and `adbd` is running. // Btw why do you want to do that? It doesn't make sense normally. Isn't `adbd` configured to authenticate the connections?

Comment: I don't know a way to check if adb is connected to a PC. Using `netstat` (and filter of lines with `adb`) you could only check if adb is active, but it does not show if it is connected via USB (adb over Wifi connections should be displayed).

Comment: @IrfanLatif I have a setup where my adb connection is a bit dodgy and the phone disappears from `adb devices`. I've seen that disabling and enabling usb debugging from the phone when that happens solves the issue, and I want to automate it, preferably without relying on an extra server. My phone is rooted, so I have full control of it.